# Tic-tac-toe game with Linked List C++

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

In one of the c++ books that I am reading, I came across one exercise that proposes me to do a tic-tac-toe game using both linked list and arrays. I decided to try with linked list first, since with arrays is obviously easier. However, I got stuck on how to check if someone won the game. Here's what I have so far:

```
struct board
{
    bool square, circle, empty;
    int pos;
    board* next;
};
void startGame(int first, board* fullBoard);
board* getBoard(board* fullBoard);


int main()
{
    int dice, first;

    board* fullBoard = NULL;
    cout << "Welcome to Tic-tac-toe DOS Game. (2 Player version)\n\n";
    cout << "X is Player 1 and O is Player 2.\nI will decide who is starting in the first match...\n ";
    srand(time(NULL));
    dice = 1;//rand() % 6 + 1;
    cout << dice;
    if(dice <= 3)
    {
        first = 1;
        cout << "Player 1 is the first!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        first = 2;
        cout << "Player 2 is the first!\n\n";
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    startGame(first, fullBoard);
}

void startGame(int first, board* fullBoard)
{
    int choice;
    bool isPlaying;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        fullBoard = getBoard(fullBoard);

    bool isGameOn = true;
    while(isGameOn == true)
    {
        board* current = fullBoard;
        while(current != NULL)
        {
            if(current->empty == true)
                cout << "   " << current->pos;
            else if(current->circle == true)
                cout << "   " << "O";
            else
                cout << "   " << "X";
            if( current->pos == 4 || current->pos == 7)
            {
                cout << "\n";
                cout << "-----------------------\n";
            }
            else if (current->pos == 1)
                cout << "\n";
            else
                cout << "   |";
            current = current->next;
        }



        if(first == 1)
        {
            isPlaying = true;
            while(isPlaying == true)
            {
                cout << "Player 1, please put the number corresponding to the area you want to fill: ";
                cin >> choice;
                while(choice < 1 || choice > 9)
                {
                    cout << "Invalid choice. Please choose a valid option: ";
                    cin >> choice;
                }
                current = fullBoard;
                while(current != NULL && current->pos != choice)
                    current = current->next;

                if(current->empty == true)
                {
                    current->empty = false;
                    current->square = true;
                    isPlaying = false;
                    first = 2;
                }
                else
                    cout << "The field that you chose is already used...\n";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            isPlaying = true;
            while(isPlaying == true)
            {
                cout << "Player 2, please put the number corresponding to the area you want to fill: ";
                cin >> choice;
                while(choice < 1 || choice > 9)
                {
                    cout << "Invalid choice. Please choose a valid option: ";
                    cin >> choice;
                }
                current = fullBoard;
                while(current != NULL && current->pos != choice)
                    current = current->next;

                if(current->empty == true)
                {
                    current->empty = false;
                    current->circle = true;
                    isPlaying = false;
                    first = 1;
                }
                else
                    cout << "The field that you chose is already used...\n";
            }
        }

        system("cls");
    }


}

board* getBoard(board* fullBoard)
{
    board* newBoard = new board;
    newBoard->empty = true;
    newBoard->circle = false;
    newBoard->square = false;
    newBoard->next = fullBoard;
    if(newBoard->next != NULL)
        newBoard->pos = newBoard->next->pos + 1;
    else
        newBoard->pos = 1;
    return newBoard;


}
```

As you can see, on my struct Board, I have an int called pos, which I created to keep track of the whole board. The only solution that I can imagine so far, is checking every single position. Ex: compare pos 8 with pos 9, 7, 5 and 2, compare pos 9 with pos 8, 7, 6, 3, 5 and 1. But I think that is way too extensive (and maybe it's hard coding as well?). What other options do you think I have?

Thanks in advance,
Felipe

Comment: Well, to begin with, you only need to compare the possible solutions that include the last position changed (if you put "X" in position 8, you do not need to check "[1, 2, 3]")

Comment: Also, I do not know if it fits the idea of the practice, but cannot you have more than one linked list? If each place of the board is included in a linked list that represents the row/column/diagonal it is in, it may be simpler (just check all the lists, but you do not have to move through them).

Comment: But that way I'd also need more pointers to store the next and previous pos in column and diagonal right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need more space to explain the "multiple lists" concept.

Your board:

```
 _ _ _
|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|
```

The lists that represent the possible solutions

```
D1  A B C  D2
    _ _ _
 E |_|_|_|
 F |_|_|_|
 G |_|_|_|
```

Note that each cell will be in at least 2 lists.

Option 1)

You store those lists in a single "list of lists". When a move is done, you iterate that list of lists, and, for each sublist (which would be A, B, etc. from the previous figure), you iterate the cells. If all the cells in a sublist are from the player who moved, you found a winner.

Option 2)

Each cell has a member that is a "list of lists". That "list of lists" holds the lists to check when a move is done in that cell (for example, for cell 1, you would have lists A, E and D1). When a move is done in a cell, you get that list from the cell and check the sublists to see if you got a winner (it is more or less the same than option 1, but limiting the lists that you have to iterate over each time).

Note that in all the cases, we are dealing only with lists (if you add the "pointer to diagonal" and similar the structure no longer is a list). Only that:

- there are many lists.
- there are lists of cells, and lists of lists of cells.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by: "if you add the "pointer to diagonal" and similar the structure no longer is a list"? I thought that linked list required pointers anyway, just like I used in my struct: 

struct board
{
    bool square, circle, empty;
    int pos;
    board* next;
};

Comment: "getDiagonalCell" is not an operation defined in a list. If you want to implement the game with a list, you use the operations defined for a list (in the case of a linked list, "firstElement", "next", "add" and "delete"). You could declare and implement a function "goToCellXY", but that is not part of the contract of the list.

Comment: Oh! I understand! I think I have enough info to finish this game now. But I still think that with array is much easier and faster, I think that that's part of the exercise though.. In any case, you helped me a lot! Thanks!